# Shift array by value, keep sorting in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array looking like this:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

How can I shift its values while maintaining the order. For instance, I'd like to start it with `'d'`:

```
new_arr = shiftArray(arr, 'd'); // => ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Are you sure your array is always unique?

Comment: Yes, it's populated by unique file-names

Comment: @idleberg Is it okay if your original array is tampered in the process?

Comment: @thefourtheye yeah, that's fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
function shiftArray(arr, target){ 
  return arr.concat(arr.splice(0,arr.indexOf(target)));
}
```

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
function shiftArray(arr, target){ 
  return arr.concat(arr.splice(0,arr.indexOf(target)));
}
alert(shiftArray(arr, 'd'));
```

Comment: it will modify the original array, is it ok?

Answer (score 5):

This will not modify the original array, also I recommend you rename the function

```
function rotateArrayAround(array, pivotNeedle) {
   var pivot = array.indexOf(pivotNeedle);   
   return array.slice(pivot).concat(array.slice(0, pivot));
}
```